# Displaying only the first item and hiding the rest with CSS - no <li>

Tags: html, css

sorry for the potentially dumb question.

I'm trying to hide three icons out of four, only want to keep the first one. The problem is, they do not seem to be part of a list.

Tried doing this:

```
.side_menu_wrapper a .social_icon li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none; }
```

But it does nothing.

The html piece looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/..." class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> //want this gone
<a href="" class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a> //want this gone 
<a href="" class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a> //want this gone
```

Is there a css solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```css
a{
  display:none;
}
a:first-child{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/..." class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook">fb</i></a>
<a href="" class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter">tw</i></a> 
<a href="" class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-pinterest">pin</i></a> 
<a href="" class="social_icon"><i class="fa fa-tumblr">tum</i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child` on other selectors, not just `li` selectors. Also, because `.social-icon` is part of the `<a>` element, you should delete the space between `a` and `.social_icon`.

`nth-child` accepts [**functional notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), which can be used to select all elements except the first:

```
.side_menu_wrapper a.social_icon:nth-child(n + 1) {
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, however, want to make sure I understand this, what does "n" stand for? Even though I had 4 elements, I put .side_menu_wrapper a.social_icon:nth-child(5) {
    display: none; 
}, then .side_menu_wrapper a.social_icon:nth-child(6) {
    display: none; 
}, then .side_menu_wrapper a.social_icon:nth-child(7) {
    display: none; 
}. Does this mean that "n" is the total number of elements, and then I do the math? Somehow this doesn't sound right...

Comment: When you use `n` in `nth-child`, the selector calculates `n` equal to `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...`, so the selector `nth-child(n)` will be equal to `nth-child(1), nth-child(2), nth-child(3), ...`. Now, because we are using `nth-child(n + 1)`, the selector will calculate `nth-child(1 + 1), nth-child(2 + 1), nth-child(3 + 1), ...` and so forth, selecting every `nth-child` except for `nth-child(1)` because we are adding `1` to each value of `n`.

Comment: The equivalent selector without using `n` in `nth-child` would be something like this: `selector:nth-child(2), selector:nth-child(3), selector:nth-child(4), ... { display: none; }` -- you would have to list out every `nth-child` except for `1`. Using `n` calculates this for us.

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.social_icon { display: none; }
a.social_icon:first-child { display: block; }
```

Hidden all `.social_icon` class and show first child of `.social_icon`

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kj9e2oyx/)